# How could I use a function in several livewire components

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-livewire

How could I use a function in several livewire components without rewriting the function each time in a new component? I have a function that disperses an event to display different notifications. I use this function in several components, but I am aware that if I always rewrite it in each component, it is an unprofessional practice. How could I avoid this?

```
public function showToastr($message, $type)
    {
        return $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('showToastr', [
            'type' => $type,
            'message' => $message
        ]);
    }
```

I tried to write the function in a service, but I get the error **Call to undefined method dispatchBrowserEvent()**

Comment: Extract it into a trait, and import the trait in those components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi it's too easy you have two option to do this

1- define a trait for you process and use your trait in any component you want
[this line](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_oop_traits.asp) tell you how you can define trait and use it

2- define a livewire component and place your function in it then you can extends this component as  any where you need to have same process